# Factorial under Modular Arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic, factorial

The problem is simple: why is it that $$n! = 0 \neq 1 = 0!\mod{}n$$
I would expect $f(n) = f(0) \mod{}n$ for any function $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$n!$ is a product that involves $n$.  As $n \equiv 0 \pmod n$ that product will evaluate to $0 \pmod n$.  $0!=1$ because it is the empty product. For your last line, how about $f(n)=\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor$?  You need to restrict the class of functions if you want that expectation to be satisfied.

Comment: Thank you for the example. I should have thought more generally about functions after writing that last line. Is there an easy way to define that restriction?

Comment: It works for any polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: There are lots of functions $\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ that to not respect the modulo operation or any other.  They are just too chaotic, but they are hard to represent.  The ring of integers does not always permit division, which is what made me think of my example.  Gerry Myerson gives a class of functions which do, but it is easy to define other functions which do as well.